# How to enable new webpart options in webpart section on a SharePoint 2013 page?

Tags: web-part, visio

I want to add Visio web part which is not available in my webpart option on my webpage.
How to enable new webpart options in webpart section on a SharePoint 2013 page?

Answer (score 4):

To be able to use the Visio webpart, Visio services must be deployed and configured.

Here is the information regarding this service from Technet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663485.aspx

And here is more about getting it up and running: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee524058.aspx

Comment: And as @alisharepoint says, you need Enterprise licens

Comment: I have started the Visio Services in the Central Admin->Application Settings->Manage Service Application but the web part is not activated in the webpart gallery. Could you pls suggest, I have tried the instructions from the link provided by you.

Comment: I have enterprise license of SharePoint in my organization. Have activated visio service application but webpart is not activated in the webpart gallery. How to do that pl. suggest.

Comment: Have you activated the SharePoint Enterprise features on sitecollection and web levels?

Answer (score 2):

are you sure? it would be under business data within the webpart gallery, its called visio web access

You also need to have the Enterprise version of SharePoint to use Visio Services to use it.

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure but the Business Data option within the webpart gallery is not there. How to activate it there?

Comment: did you manage to fix the issue? did you enable the feature at the site collection level to enable the viso webpart within the webpart gallery??